# textAngular header button cannot be larger?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, textangular

Currently, I'm using textAngular for my project. I'm trying to increase toolbar button and add label under that button. Problem is even I can increase button except H1, H2, H3 and cannot able to add label under each icon.

[image]

```
        taOptions.classes = {
            focussed: 'focussed',
            toolbar: 'btn-toolbar',
            toolbarGroup: 'btn-group btn-group-lg',
            toolbarButton: 'btn btn-default btn-lg',
            toolbarButtonActive: 'active',
            disabled: 'disabled',
            textEditor: 'form-control',
            htmlEditor: 'form-control'
        };
```

Comment: Can you add a plnkr please

Comment: @VVK that code and image is the best example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option `ta-toolbar-button-class` on `text-angular` element with the desired css classes. These classes will be applied to the toolbar buttons.

For example you can add bootstrap classes `btn btn-lg` like `ta-toolbar-button-class="btn btn-lg"` on `text-angular` div. This will increase the size of all buttons equally.

See Here : **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pow3cc44IcvfAKEmMw3g?p=preview)**